# Is this old news? $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i!}{p_i\#} \approx 1.240053652689\dots$

Tags: soft-question, factorial, constants, primorial

This is a soft question as it arises out of my curiosity alone. I noticed that as $n$ increases, $\frac{n!}{p_n\#}$ decreases in magnitude much faster than $\frac{1}{p_n}$, and I wondered if the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i!}{p_i\#}$$ was convergent. A preliminary calculation showed that the sum very rapidly converges to $1.240053652689\dots$

A quick search for this number and did not find any reports of it. **My question is:** Is this number a known constant, or can anyone suggest an algebraic relationship of this number to other know constants? Please don't waste a lot of time looking for abstruse expressions; just respond if you happen to recognize this number.

Comment: What is the hashtag, and what is $p_n$?

Comment: Looks to be the product of the first $n$ primes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial

Comment: I cannot answer your questions as asked, but it is no surprise to me that $\frac{i!}{p_i\#}$ converges so rapidly. For this is $\frac{i(i-1)(i-2) \ldots 1}{p_ip_{i-1} \ldots 2}$, and $j/p_j$ is about $(\log j)^{-1} << 1/2$. So $\frac{i!}{p_i\#} << (1/2)^i$.

Answer (score 1):

*Just for the fun !*

Wtih an absolute error of $4.45\times 10^{-22}$, this number corresponds to the positive root of the pentic polynomial
$$284 x^5+1154 x^4-1342 x^3+571 x^2-1502 x-18=0$$ which is not found by the $ISC$.

Comment: If this root is so close it is strange that ISC does not find this possible closed form.

Comment: @Peter. The ISC does not like too much quintic polynomials. This has been my homework ! Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It would be exceedingly interesting if this were a solvable quintic.

Answer (score 0):

in terms of justifying convergence:
$$i!=i(i-1)(i-2)...1$$
$$p_i\#=p_{i-1}\#...(5)(3)(2)(1)$$
you could probably find a nice explicit way of comparing the orders of these two functions using $\operatorname{li}(x)\approx\pi(x)$

---

As you said, [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1.240053652689&language=english&go=Search) returned no results nor did [inverse symbolic calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=1.240053652689&lookup_type=simple). I would certainly be interested if there is any relationship to other functions or properties of it (transcendental etc)

Comment: I thought $p_i \# = p_i \times p_{i-1} \#$.....

Comment: Note that $$
\log (p_n \# ) = \vartheta (p_n ) = n\left( {\log n + \log \log n - 1 + O\!\left( {\frac{{\log \log n}}{{\log n}}} \right)} \right)
$$ and $$
\log n! = \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\log n - n + O(1).
$$ Thus $$
\log \left( {\frac{{n!}}{{p_n \# }}} \right) =  - n\log \log n\left( {1 + O\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log n}}} \right)} \right).
$$

Comment: $p_i$# is simply the product of the first $i$ prime numbers. So Mike is right , but his comment above saves the day and explains the quick convergence.

Comment: The quick convergence speaks for a transcendental number , maybe Roth's theorem allows a proof.

Comment: @Mike yes sorry you are correct that was a typing error by me